# DataGridView ColumnOrder Change on refreshing

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I am trying to populate a DataGridView in window form in C#. Some columns in the grid are dynamic that means the no. of columns can be vary on refreshing the grid.these dynamic columns are resident between some columns in the datagrid. My problem is when i refreshing the datagrid by repopulating it with new datasource, it place the newer columns at last (after all the columns) but I want these should be placed with all the dynamic columns.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Show the code that populates your gridView

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource = Results;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.Columns.Clear();
dataGridView.DataSource = data;
```

With auto-generate columns property enabled, extra (unmapped) columns are appended to the end. You can unbind and re-bind to fix it; set the DataSource to null and back to the table